# mongodb - find every last document from a property-type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document-scheme like this:

```
{      
  "pair":"BTCUSDT",
  "ask":{
    "amount":33107101.800000004,
    "total":507,
    "high":72000,
    "low":65132
},
  "bid":{
    "amount":32368164.399999995,
    "total":498,
    "high":65131.99,
    "low":60200.2
},
  "updateStamp":1636632371639
}
```

now my DB there are documents with different values in `pair` and also documents with the same value. Some of them have a `updateStamp` that is, lets say a few seconds old, and some have a `updateStamp` that is a few minutes old or older.

*(I wrote simpler values in `updateStamp` for simplicity)*

```
{      
  "pair":"BTCUSDT",
  "ask": ...,
  "updateStamp": 100
},
{      
  "pair":"BTCUSDT",
  "ask": ...,
  "updateStamp": 200
},
{      
  "pair":"ETHUDST",
  "ask": ...,
  "updateStamp": 500
},
{      
  "pair":"ETHUDST",
  "ask": ...,
  "updateStamp": 200
},
{      
  "pair":"DOGEUSDT",
  "ask": ...,
  "updateStamp": 600
},
```

Now I want to compare every latest document of a `pair` and find the 10 documents, for the pairs with the largest `ask.total`-value. Simple saif, like a Top-10 from the latest of every pair.

But I don't get it how do manage this? I have been fiddeling around with aggregation and multiple finds for a while now. Maybe someone knows how to solve this?

Comment: [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n_jyE6gHz5t) could be what you are looking for. It would be helpful if you can give us a concrete sample dataset and correpsonding expected output so that we can test out the expected behaviour.

Comment: Boy, that seems really to do the trick!! Tank you so much! :) Can you please explain the `$match`-expression, as I can not find anything about `$$p` on the web?

Answer (score 0):

You can first `$group` by `pair`. Then use the result to perform [sub-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup) `$lookup` to fetch the "last 10" documents.

In the sub-pipeline:

1. `$match` with `pair`; [let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-let) is used to assign the value in grouped `pair` into variable `p`; which is later refered to as `$$p`. The `$match` means the variable `$$p` is equals to `pair` in the `$lookup`, which is equal to we only getting record related to that specific `pair`
2. `$sort` by `updateStamp`
3. `$limit` by 10

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$pair"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      let: {
        p: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$pair",
                "$$p"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            updateStamp: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 10
        }
      ],
      "as": "output array field"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n_jyE6gHz5t) for your reference.